# Selenium: Follow adfly redirect

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Im trying to make a bot that visits my adfly link using the chrome webdriver. Every time I try to use the code below though, the webdriver tells me that there were too many redirects and doesn't follow through. The code below is just being used for testing at the moment:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--proxy-server="+"http://102.129.249.120:8080")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get("http://raboninco.com/18Whc")
```

[Image of error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UEPv.png)

Comment: try: `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=102.129.249.120:8080')` instead

Comment: Thanks for the shorten, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Hmm, then you probably reached the request limit for the page with that proxy. Try to test it with another proxy (or https instead). Depending on the scale you could try to loop through a proxylist containing multiple proxys.

Comment: Well that sort of worked. Now im getting an access denied error. Possibly because they can detect fake views?

Comment: Hard to tell, it's hard to bot on these sites without knowing how their protection system works in detail. Maybe they lookup your browser-fingerprint / User-Agent etc. or the page that liked your there. You can't really do much except other than try different methods.

Comment: What other methods could there be? (from the point of view of a noob)

Comment: Also, i just tried using a socks5 proxy and it gave me a 502 error. Gonna keep trying different proxies...

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i figured it out. I can use tor with selenium to get access to adfly. Works great btw. Thanks for the help and time guys. If you want to see the code I  used, here it is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

os.popen(r'C:\Users\joldb\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--proxy-server="+"socks5://127.0.0.1:9050")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get("http://raboninco.com/18Whc")
```